# How do you implement active-low reset with named ports?

Tags: chisel

I'm attempting to use Records along with 'withClockAndReset()' to create an interface Vivado will use, along with the expected negated reset.

The approach so far looks like:

```scala
// Borrowed from https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/RecordSpec.scala
final class CustomBundle(elts: (String, Data)*) extends Record {
  val elements = ListMap(elts map { case (field, elt) =>
    requireIsChiselType(elt)
    field -> elt
  }: _*)
  def apply(elt: String): Data = elements(elt)
  override def cloneType: this.type = {
    val cloned = elts.map { case (n, d) => n -> DataMirror.internal.chiselTypeClone(d) }
    (new CustomBundle(cloned: _*)).asInstanceOf[this.type]
  }
}

class vivadoSlaveWrapper(regCount:Int, addrBits: Int, dataBits:Int) extends RawModule {
  val io = IO(new CustomBundle(
    "aclk"            -> Input(Clock()),
    "aresetn"         -> Input(Bool()),

    "s_axi_awaddr"    -> Input(UInt(addrBits.W)),
    "s_axi_awvalid"   -> Input(Bool()),
    "s_axi_awready"   -> Output(Bool()),
    "s_axi_awprot"    -> Input(UInt(3.W)),

    "s_axi_bresp"     -> Output(UInt(2.W)),
    "s_axi_bvalid"    -> Output(Bool()),
    "s_axi_bready"    -> Input(Bool()),

    "s_axi_wdata"     -> Input(UInt(dataBits.W)),
    "s_axi_wvalid"    -> Input(Bool()),
    "s_axi_wready"    -> Output(Bool()),
    "s_axi_wstrb"     -> Input(UInt({dataBits/8}.W)),

    "s_axi_araddr"    -> Input(UInt(addrBits.W)),
    "s_axi_arvalid"   -> Input(Bool()),
    "s_axi_arready"   -> Output(Bool()),
    "s_axi_arprot"    -> Input(UInt(3.W)),

    "s_axi_rdata"     -> Output(UInt(dataBits.W)),
    "s_axi_rvalid"    -> Output(Bool()),
    "s_axi_rready"    -> Input(Bool()),
    "s_axi_rresp"     -> Output(UInt(2.W))
  ))
  withClockAndReset(io("aclk"), ~io("aresetn")) {
    val mod = Module( new simpleRegBank(regCount, addrBits, dataBits) )

    mod.io.aw.addr      := io("s_axi_awaddr" )
    mod.io.aw.valid     := io("s_axi_awvalid")
    io("s_axi_awready") := mod.io.aw.ready
    mod.io.aw.prot      := io("s_axi_awprot" )
    io("s_axi_bresp"  ) := mod.io.b.bits
    io("s_axi_bvalid" ) := mod.io.b.valid
    mod.io.b.ready      := io("s_axi_bready" )
    mod.io.w.data       := io("s_axi_wdata"  )
    mod.io.w.valid      := io("s_axi_wvalid" )
    io("s_axi_wready" ) := mod.io.w.ready
    mod.io.w.strb       := io("s_axi_wstrb"  )
    mod.io.ar.addr      :=io("s_axi_araddr" )
    mod.io.ar.valid     := io("s_axi_arvalid") 
    io("s_axi_arready") := mod.io.ar.ready
    mod.io.ar.prot      := io("s_axi_arprot" )
    io("s_axi_rdata"  ) := mod.io.r.data
    io("s_axi_rvalid" ) := mod.io.r.valid
    mod.io.r.ready      := io("s_axi_rready" )
    io("s_axi_rresp"  ) := mod.io.r.resp
  }
}
```

but this results in errors around which types are being used in this case. I suspect this is mostly a Scala question, but I'm not quite sure how to resolve this to work for Clock and Reset.

The error is as below:

```
[error] /.../chisel/src/main/scala/axi4lite/axi4lite.scala:219:23: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.Data
[error]     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.Data
[error]  required: chisel3.core.Clock
[error]   withClockAndReset(io("aclk"), io("aresetn")) {
[error]                       ^
[error] /.../chisel/src/main/scala/axi4lite/axi4lite.scala:219:35: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.Data
[error]     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.Data
[error]  required: chisel3.core.Reset
[error]   withClockAndReset(io("aclk"), io("aresetn")) {
[error]                                   ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```